# MySQLi Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

I keep getting this error when deleting from a database. It worked on a different server, no error message. I'm scratching my head here. $id is a number (the id column in the MySQL table) and I can't figure it out. I've seen a few answers that matched my code, but I still get it. Here's the code.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'table');

// get id number
$id=$_GET['page'];

if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ("
    . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
}

$query =
        "DELETE FROM listing WHERE id='$id'";
$conn = $db->prepare($query);

// the problem line
 $conn->bind_param('i', $id);
if ($conn->execute()) {
print "Successfully deleted the entry";

} else {
    echo ' No ';


$db->close();

}
```

Comment: In the query you are preparing you are using a variable where you should be using a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

The point of preparing is to not insert the variable directly - that is, so that you don't have to do `WHERE id='$id'`. Instead, mysqli takes care of this for you. In fact, you don't even need the quotes.

What you want is to put a placeholder there, like this:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM listing WHERE id = ?";
```

Then, when you bind the parameter later, the system looks for the placeholder:

```
$conn->bind_param('i', $id);
```

The `'i'` means to treat the `$id` as an integer.